# Unable to write Teamchannel message using Addasync call

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Basically we are migrating Teams to Teams using below API permissions For Read & Write of Teams.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xoc6.png)

earlier we were suppose to create new project add this api permission and submit protected api form for approval ,after that our teams to teams migrations was done properly , but after microsoft new update of no longer need to submit protected api forms we are facing issue while writing TeamsChannelMessage we are using Teamwork.Migrate.All api to write TeamsChannelMessage using below method

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRRb4.png)

```
                if (MessageItem.IsReplyMessage)
                {
                    //#-- Posting a reply to the message --#//
                    
                    IChatMessageRepliesCollectionRequest ReplyRequest =
                        this.TeamService.Teams[MessageItem.ParentItemIDPath[0]].Channels[MessageItem.ParentItemIDPath[1]].Messages[MessageItem.ParentItemID].Replies.Request();

                    DestinationItem = MicrosoftHelper.InvokeApiCall(() => { return ReplyRequest.AddAsync(SourceChatMessage).Result; }, this);
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    //#-- Posting the message in channel --#//
                    IChannelMessagesCollectionRequest messageRequest =
                       this.TeamService.Teams[MessageItem.ParentItemIDPath[0]].Channels[MessageItem.ParentItemIDPath[1]].Messages.Request();

                    DestinationItem = MicrosoftHelper.InvokeApiCall(() =>
                    { return messageRequest.AddAsync(SourceChatMessage).Result; }, this);
                }
```

While processing messages we are  getting exception of( Requested API is not Supported) or (Unkonwn Error).

we are not able to migrate a single TeamsChannelMessage .

We need an efficient solution for issue as soon as possible.We would greatly appreciate it if you could spare some time to look into this matter and help us out with the resolution.

Please be in touch at your earliest convenience so that we can figure out how to best solve this problem.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The same issue is being tracked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1303535/issue-regarding-teamchannelmessage-are-not-getting. Please follow the thread for further updates. Thank you.